# Perl script for batch file processing

Tags: perl, bash

I have a relatively simple question for you experts. I have 300 files in a directory that I want to process with my perl script (shown below). I was wondering if there is a way to use a variable and process in a batch of files in perl. I have a file containing a list of file name if this helps.
Your feedback will be appreciated.

====================================

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open (FILE1, "001.txt") or die ("Can't open file $!");

while(<FILE1>){
        my $line = $_;
        chomp $line;
        if ( $line =~ m/^chr/ ) {
            open OUT, '>>', '001_tmp.txt';
            print OUT "$line\n";
            }
}
close(OUT);
close(FILE1);
```

======================================

Clarification:
Basically I want the perl script that is equivalent to the following shell script where I can accommodate all files using the variable.

```
#!/bin/bash 
if [[ $# != 1 ]] 
then 
   echo "Usage: error <input>" 
else 
   echo $# $1 
   export input=$1 
   grep "^chr" $1 > ${input}_tmp.vcf
```

Comment: What is your question?  Also, you should use the three-arg version of open.

Comment: OK. I will use the three-arg version.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, please clarify by editing your Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want your `while` loop to read through each file in some given directory..

I would do something like this:

Use [`opendir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/opendir.html) and [`readdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) so you can get the file names to operate on.

I would also look at [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) to filter out the files you don't care about, in my example I filter out  directories...

```
opendir(my $dh, $dir) or die "$dir: $!";
my @files = grep { !-d $_ } readdir $dh;
closedir $dh;
```

Now you will have a list of files to do work on...

```
for my $file (@files) {
    open my $fh, "<", $file or die "$!";
    while( my $line = <$fh> ) {
        #TODO: stuff
    }
    close $fh;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works flawlessly except I had to put last; to get out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Your tags indicated batch-file, meaning Windows batch file.  If that's not what you mean, disregard this. :-)

Perhaps something like this:

From a batch file:

```
for /f %%x in (listoffilenames.txt) do (
    perl myperlscript.pl %%x
)
```

And then your Perl script can be modified like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# You may want to add a little more error handling 
# around getting the filename, etc.
my $filename = shift or die "No filename specified.";

open (FILE1, "<", $filename) or die ("Can't open file $!");

while(<FILE1>){
        my $line = $_;
        chomp $line;
        if ( $line =~ m/^chr/ ) {
            open OUT, '>>', "temp-$filename";
            print OUT "$line\n";
            }
}
close(OUT);
close(FILE1);
```